# Passportjs: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined at Strategy._verify

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

Using passportjs for authentication in my node.js application but getting the error above. This is my code below

**app.js**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'},function(email, password, res, done) {
    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);

        if (err) {return done(err)};

        if (user.length === 0) {
            done(null, false);
        };

        const hash = user[0].password.toString();
        console.log(hash);

        bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
            if (res === true) {
                return done(null, {user_id: user[0].id});
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    });
}
));
```

**index.js**

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: 'home',
    failureRedirect: '/'
}));
```

What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Please quote the thrown error.

Comment: The error is `Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined`

Comment: `res.locals` is undefined. Why not exporting your database connection using singleton?

Comment: Let me explore that, never done it before. I will comment if it works out well